# Auto-loading declined when trying to use gdb with MPI?

Tags: c++, linux, unix, gdb, mpi

I have a program that works serially, but when I try to use openMPI, I get the message

```
 mpirun noticed that the job aborted, but has no info as to the process that caused that situation.
```

For the serial program, I run valgrind by typing

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes --tool=memcheck /workspace/MK/cmake/Project/buildagain/bin/Project -PR INPUT/chain.inp`
```

Since I run the program serially by typing, `./runProj.sh type.txt` and following the link  http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=debugging#memchecker_run
to run MPI with valgrind, I typed

```
mpirun -np 4 valgrind  /workspace/MK/cmake/Project/buildagain/bin/Project -PR INPUT/chain.inp
```

However, the output is very short, so I cannot see where the problem is occurring

So I tried using gdb with MPI. I typed

```
 mpirun -np 2 xterm -e gdb ../cmake/Project/buildagain/bin/Project
```

I got the following output

```
 [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
  warning: File "opt/apps/ossw/applications/gcc/gcc-4.7/sl6/lib63/libstdc++.so.6.0.17-gdb.py" auto-loading has been declined by your 'auto-load safe-path' set to ...
To enable execution of this file add ...
line to your configuration file "h1/MK/.gdbinit"
 ....
```

when I type `show auto-load safe-path` ,the out put is

```
 List of directories from which it is safe to auto-load files is usr/share/gdb/auto-load:/usr/lib/debug:/usr/bin/mono-gdb.py
```

When I type the below I get the same output as before:

```
 run -PR INP/Chain.inp -iex "set auto-load safe-path /usr/share/gdb/auto-load"
```

or

```
 run -PR INP/Chain.inp -iex "set auto-load safe-path /opt/apps/ossw/applications/gcc/gcc-4.7/sl6/lib63/libstdc++.so.6.0.17-gdb.py"
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2):

GDB from an Xterm from mpirun is possible, but your mpi implementation might make this harder to accomplish.

Say you've got a hello-mpi you want to debug:

```
$ mpiexec -np 4 xterm -e 'gdb hello-mpi'
```

With mpich, this will get me four xterms all running gdb (as you can imagine, it's not terribly practical for more than a few processes.

I just tried this with a recent-ish OpenMPI, and got the same result.

But that isn't your problem, as you already tried that.  Your problem is that your libraries are in places GDB doesn't expect to look.  Here's how I update my auto-load-safe path:

At the top of ~/.gdbinit I have a few lines:

```
add-auto-load-safe-path /home/robl/work/mpich/code_toybox
add-auto-load-safe-path /home/robl/work/build/mpich/src/mpi/romio/test
...
```

This creates a white-list of places where GDB expects to find a .gdbinit file

(by the way, you probably want 'set breakpoint pending on' in there, too)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your trying to launch gdb from within xterm from within mpirun, which I would say you cannot do. But I never used X with mpi. Nor gdb for that matter.

You can use `gdb` to `attach` to the running process. So launch your program normally with mpirun, find the process id and attach to it using `gdb <progname> <pid>`. If you do this and still get the load error, edit the question, I'll delete this answer, and maybe someone else will help.

If it works, or if it fails because the program terminates before you can attach to it, you need to put a pause-loop at the beginning. Usually the way to handle this is some piece of code at the beginning of the program that pauses the program until you've gone in with the debugger and changed a flag. Make a call to `pause` and define that function this way:

```
pause() { 
 int pause;
 struct timeval tv = {1,500000}; /* 1.5 seconds */
 while (pause==1) { select(0,NULL,NULL,NULL,&tv); }` 
}
```

You could also do an MPI-BARRIER, but perhaps the problem is that MPI_INIT is failing or doing something screwy. If it's ok, you can use the barrier like the sleep function. You can also use the node-id to pause only on the node you want to debug.

Comment: For a sample helloworld program, I can get a pause using your `pause` method. However, I'm not seeing a pause with my actual program. Is there another method you can suggest?

Comment: *eyes wide open*  I think I'd have to see a sample portion of your code. I've not done anything with MPI in ... over 6 years. So maybe things changed and they've pushed the init into the _main (which calls main) or something esoteric.